# Is the set of extensive, increasing, ∅-preserving operators 2^X→2^X closed under composition?

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology

Let $\Bbb E (X)$ denote the set of all operators $f:2^{X} \rightarrow 2^{X}$ such that:

1. $f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$
2. $A \subseteq f(A)$
3. $A \subseteq B \implies f(A) \subseteq f(B)$
4. $a \in f(A \cup \{b\}) \setminus f(A) \implies b \in f(A \cup \{a\}) $

Is $\Bbb E (X)$ closed under composition?

It's the final lemma I would need for a theorem I'm struggling with for few days now, but I don't really know how to approach it. There are two potentially helpful facts I was able to prove:

**Fact 1** For any $f:2^{X} \rightarrow 2^{X}$ such that $f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ there is $F \in \Bbb E (X)$ such that:

1. $f(A) \subseteq F(A) $ for every $ A \subseteq X$
2. If $ g \in \Bbb E (X)$ and $f(A) \subseteq g(A) $ for every $ A \subseteq X$ then $F(A) \subseteq g(A) $ for every $ A \subseteq X$

**Fact 2** If $ \mathcal F \subseteq \Bbb E (X)$ is totally ordered by inclusion, ie. if for each $f,g \in \mathcal F$ either $f(A) \subseteq g(A) $ for every $ A \subseteq X$ or $g(A) \subseteq f(A) $ for every $ A \subseteq X$ then $[\bigcup \mathcal F](A)=\bigcup \{f(A) : f \in \mathcal F\} \in \Bbb E (X)$

Thererefore the structure of $\Bbb E (X)$ is somewhat similar to that of a convexity (see: M.L.J. van de Vel, "Theory of Convex Structures"), might well be a dead end though.

Comment: When I search for the words "stable for compositions" on Google, this question is the first result and the few results that follow are about nanoalloy configurations. So could you please define what you mean?

Comment: @MishaLavrov I mean $f,g \in\Bbb E(X) \Rightarrow f \circ g \in \Bbb E(X)$ - I was sure the term is generally well-known, since one can speak about stability for intersections, nested unions etc. - thanks for correcting me!

Comment: I would say "closed under composition" but now I see what you mean.

Comment: Great thanks! I was using van de Vel's terminology which may well be outtdated/niche/borrowed from Dutch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, it's not.**

The first three properties are fine, but property 4 doesn't survive in general. Here is a counterexample.

Define $f: 2^{\{1,2,3\}} \to 2^{\{1,2,3\}}$ by
$$
   f(\varnothing)=\varnothing,\; f(\{1\}) = \{1\},\; f(\{2\}) = f(\{3\}) = \{2,3\},\\f(\{1,2\}) = f(\{1,3\}) = f(\{2,3\}) = f(\{1,2,3\}) = \{1,2,3\}.
$$
It takes a bit of checking, but we can verify that all four properties hold for $f$.

However, $f(f(\{1\})) = \{1\}$ while $f(f(\{2\})) = \{1,2,3\}$, which means that
$$
   1 \in f(f(\varnothing \cup \{2\})) \setminus f(f(\varnothing)) \\
   2 \notin f(f(\varnothing \cup\{1\}))
$$
so the composition $f \circ f$ violates property 4 for $a = 1$, $b=2$, $A = \varnothing$.

Comment: Ok, this solution sure is legit - although, of course, it's a major setbeck for me. I'm curious whether additional condition of singleton-preserving (ie. $f(\{a\})=\{a\}$ ) would change anything - this affects the structure in a significant way and would still help me a bit, but I think asking it now in a separate question would be in a verge of spam, so I'll try to do something myself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I expect that adding that condition wouldn't change anything; you would have to go further up the lattice to create a similar construction, and the solution would be more complicated, but essentially the same.

Comment: Do you mind if i PM you with original formulation of my problem? It concerns a class of operators, whose elements I can construct but not yet fully characterize: they certainly belong to $\Bbb E(X)$ but seem to have a load of additional properties. The comment format is a bit too short to contain the description and I do not yet want to post it as a separate question.

Comment: I'd prefer not; the likeliest outcome is that I wouldn't be able to help you, plus the weekend is over so I have my own math problems to start thinking about again. Sorry!

Comment: It's ok, thanks anyway